# Public ip socket networking

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a server object and client object that can connect and communicate with each other.

The client connects using the servers private IP address.

But I would like to be able to use public IP addresses to be able to communicate over the internet.

I get the public ip address using a url www.whatsmyip.com as a url.

I paste this public ip address where needed, but the client is unable to seemingly find the server using the public IP address

Comment: Most likely the firewall on your router hasn't been configured to allow this.  And no you can't configure this from Java, you have to configure your router using it's built in web server.

Comment: There are several points where this can go wrong. Post some code? Have you tried to ping the public address (url) to see if it's reachable?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Adding arbitrary italics is not 'improved formatting'. It is just creating a mess for others to clean up.

Comment: Arbitrary italics @NaveenKumar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with code, as long as the server is binding to INADDR_ANY. It has to do with correct port forwarding at the server-side firewall.

Comment: So you cant forward it within java?